# Removing nodes from an XmlDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

The following code should find the appropriate project tag and remove it from the XmlDocument, however when I test it, it says:

**The node to be removed is not a child of this node.**

Does anyone know the proper way to do this?

```
public void DeleteProject (string projectName)
{
    string ccConfigPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConfigPath"];

    XmlDocument configDoc = new XmlDocument();

    configDoc.Load(ccConfigPath);

    XmlNodeList projectNodes = configDoc.GetElementsByTagName("project");

    for (int i = 0; i < projectNodes.Count; i++)
    {
        if (projectNodes[i].Attributes["name"] != null)
        {
            if (projectName == projectNodes[i].Attributes["name"].InnerText)
            {                                                
                configDoc.RemoveChild(projectNodes[i]);
                configDoc.Save(ccConfigPath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Fixed. I did two things:

```
XmlNode project = configDoc.SelectSingleNode("//project[@name='" + projectName + "']");
```

Replaced the For loop with an XPath query, which wasn't for fixing it, just because it was a better approach.

The actual fix was:

```
project.ParentNode.RemoveChild(project);
```

Thanks Pat and Chuck for this suggestion.

Comment: I was looking for just this thing. I spent a half a day looking for xml stuff on the internet and half a minute on SO. Yet another reason why Jeff and Joel were on to something.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Instead of

```
configDoc.RemoveChild(projectNodes[i]);
```

try

```
projectNodes[i].parentNode.RemoveChild(projectNodes[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
configDoc.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(projectNodes[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to select the parent node of projectNodes[i] before calling RemoveChild.

Answer (score 2):

When you get sufficiently annoyed by writing it the long way (for me that was fairly soon) you can use a helper extension method provided below. Yay new technology!

```
public static class Extensions {
    ...
    public static XmlNode RemoveFromParent(this XmlNode node) {
        return (node == null) ? null : node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
    }
}
...
//some_long_node_expression.parentNode.RemoveChild(some_long_node_expression);
some_long_node_expression.RemoveFromParent();
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the project nodes aren't child nodes, but grandchildren or lower?  GetElementsByTagName will give you elements from anywhere in the child element tree, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

It would be handy to see a sample of the XML file you're processing but my guess would be that you have something like this

```
<Root>
 <Blah>
   <project>...</project>
 </Blah>
</Root>
```

The error message seems to be because you're trying to remove `<project>` from the grandparent rather than the direct parent of the project node