# How to delete xml element with C#?

Tags: xml

I'm new to XML and am having a problem understanding how to implement a solution of deleting certain elements within the tree.  I've searched for a solution and have tried numerous examples, but have not generated anything that satisfies me.  Hoping that someone may shed some light.  Probably real simply, but I'm missing it since I'm just starting with XML.

A sample XML would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.sm">
          <section name="domainServices" type="System.sm.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServicesSection, System.sm.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" allowDefinition="MachineTABCplication" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="useRemote" value="false" />
        <add key="sandboxFolder" value="D:\Sandbox" />
        <add key="imageFilesFolder" value="Images" />
      </appSettings>
      <runtime>
        <assemblylock xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <probing privatePath="Platform/bin;ProductBin" />
        </assemblylock>
      </runtime>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <system.web>
        <httpModules>
          <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.sm.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.sm.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </httpModules>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms protection="All" />
        </authentication>
        <roleManager enabled="true">
        </roleManager>
        <profile>
          <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
          </providers>
          <properties>
            <add name="FriendlyName" />
          </properties>
        </profile>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" />
      </system.web>
      <system.ws>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
          <add name="DomainServiceModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.sm.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.sm.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </modules>
      </system.ws>
      <system.sm>
        <client>
          <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:5256/HTM" lock="netTcplock" lockConfiguration="NetTcplock_Service" contract="ProductHFSReference.Service" name="NetTcplock_Service" />
          <endpoint address="http://localhost:5255/HTM/basic" lock="basicHttplock" lockConfiguration="BasicHttplock_Service" contract="ProductHFSReference.Service" name="BasicHttplock_Service" />
          <endpoint address="http://localhost:5255/HTM/ws" lock="wsHttplock" lockConfiguration="WSHttplock_Service1" contract="ProductHFSReference.Service" name="WSHttplock_Service1" />
          <endpoint address="http://localhost:5255/DManager/ws" lock="wsHttplock" lockConfiguration="WSHttplock_IDevicePool" contract="DManagerServiceReference.IDevicePool" name="WSHttplock_IDevicePool">
            <deleteme>
              <userName value="Jack" />
            </deleteme>
          </endpoint>
          <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:5256/DManager" lock="netTcplock" lockConfiguration="NetTcplock_IDevicePool" contract="DManagerServiceReference.IDevicePool" name="NetTcplock_IDevicePool">
            <deleteme>
              <userName value="Jill" />
            </deleteme>
          </endpoint>
        </client>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
            <!-- Enable the serializer to serialize greater number of records -->
            <behavior name="SilverlightWCFLargeDataApplication.Web.SilverlightWCFServiceBehavior">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <locks>
          <basicHttplock>
            <lock name="BasicHttplock_IApplication" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="524288" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
              <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
              </security>
            </lock>
            <lock name="BasicHttplock_ILicenseManagerService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
              <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
              </security>
            </lock>
          </basicHttplock>
          <customlock>
            <lock name="ProductWebApp.Web.Services.positionPreviewSvc.customlock0">
              <binaryMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="2147483647" maxWritePoolSize="2147483647" maxSessionSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="200000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
              </binaryMessageEncoding>
              <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
            </lock>
          </customlock>
          <netTcplock>
            <lock name="NetTcplock_IDevicePool" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
              <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
              <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
              </security>
            </lock>
            <lock name="NetTcplock_Service" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
              <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
              <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
              </security>
            </lock>
            <lock name="NetTcplock_IProductAppSvc" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
              <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
              <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
              </security>
            </lock>
            </lock>
          </netTcplock>
          <wsHttplock>
            <lock name="WSHttplock_Service" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
              <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
              <security mode="Message">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" />
              </security>
            </lock>
          </wsHttplock>
        </locks>
        <services>
          <service name="ProductWebApp.Web.Services.positionPreviewSvc">
            <endpoint address="" lock="customlock" lockConfiguration="ProductWebApp.Web.Services.positionPreviewSvc.customlock0" contract="ProductWebApp.Web.Services.positionPreviewSvc" />
            <endpoint address="mex" lock="mexHttplock" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          </service>
          <service name="ProductWebApp.Web.Services.positionPresetSvc">
            <endpoint address="" lock="customlock" lockConfiguration="ProductWebApp.Web.Services.positionPresetSvc.customlock0" contract="ProductWebApp.Web.Services.positionPresetSvc" />
            <endpoint address="mex" lock="mexHttplock" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          </service>
          <service name="ProductWebApp.Web.Services.ProductSvc">
            <endpoint address="" lock="customlock" lockConfiguration="ProductWebApp.Web.Services.ProductSvc.customlock0" contract="ProductWebApp.Web.Services.ProductSvc" />
            <endpoint address="mex" lock="mexHttplock" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          </service>
        </services>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSitelocksEnabled="true" />
      </system.sm>
    </configuration>
```

I'm trying to go through the XML and remove all instances of the element `<deleteme>`.

I've tried looping through XmlNodes to obtain any childnodes with name equal to "deleteme" then call the removeall().  This removes everything except the `<deleteme></deleteme>` tags.  What would I need to do the remove `<deleteme></deleteme>` entirely?

Thanks in advance for your time and guidance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing nodes from an XmlDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611/removing-nodes-from-an-xmldocument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have found the node to remove use this call:

```
node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
```

That will bring you back to the parent and then remove the entire node(including the tags)