# How to read in some XML then split out various nodes/elements in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have some xml (in a file, but can be a string) which I need to parse, e.g.:

```
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlText);
```

Given the following XML:

```
<foo>
    <cat>...</cat>
    <cat>...</cat>
    <dog>...</dog>
    <cat>...</cat>
    <dog>...</dog>
</foo>
```

I'm not sure how I can extract all the `cat` and `dog` elements and put them into the following output :-

```
<foo>
    <cat>...</cat>
    <cat>...</cat>
    ....
</foo>
```

and the same with dogs.

What's the trick to extract those nodes and put them into separate `XMLDocuments`.

Comment: Is Linq-to-XML an option for you?

Answer (score 8):

Use Linq to XML as it has a much nicer API.

```
var doc = XElement.Parse(
@"<foo>
    <cat>...</cat>
    <cat>...</cat>
    <dog>...</dog>
    <cat>...</cat>
    <dog>...</dog>
</foo>");
doc.Descendants("dog").Remove();
```

`doc` now contains this:

```
<foo>
    <cat>...</cat>
    <cat>...</cat>
    <cat>...</cat>
</foo>
```

**Edit:**

While Linq to XML itself provides a nice API to work with XML, the power of Linq and its projection capabilities enables you to shape your data as you see fit.

Consider this, for example. Here the descendant elements are grouped by name and projected into a new `root` element which is then wrapped into a `XDocument`. Note that this creates an enumerable of `XDocument`.

```
var docs= 
    from d in doc.Descendants()
    group d by d.Name into g
    select new XDocument(
        new XElement("root", g)
    );
```

`docs` now contains:

```
<root>
    <cat>...</cat>
    <cat>...</cat>
    <cat>...</cat>
</root>
---
<root>
    <dog>...</dog>
    <dog>...</dog>
</root>
```

Oh, by the way. The `Descendants` method goes through *all* descendant elements, use `Elements` if you only want the immediate child elements.

Here are the [Linq to XML docs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx)

Comment: Could u use linq and flip it .. so it only EXTRACTS the cat (or dog) elements? (i have multiple element's types to extract)

Comment: @Pure.Krome some experimentation on your part would answer that question faster than you typed it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way will be to use XSLT and apply it on you `XMLDocument` in such way you won't modify your source and have as much outputs as you need.

The code for applying transform is

```
    XslCompiledTransform xslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();          
    xslTransform.Load("cat.xslt");
    xslTransform.Transform(doc.CreateNavigator(),null, writer);
    return writer.ToString();
```

And the simple `cat.xslt` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="foo">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select = "cat" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to create one XSLT each for cat, dog, and so on?

Comment: @RGraham It depends how real problem looks like. You can easy duplicate nodes in XSLT

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `XmlDocument`: Load it twice from the same file and remove the unwanted nodes. Here is a link that shows you how: [Removing nodes from an XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611/removing-nodes-from-an-xmldocument).

```
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlText);
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
nodeList = root.SelectNodes("//cat");

foreach (XmlNode node on nodeList)
{
  root.RemoveChild(node);
}
```