# ADD and DELETE section in web.config

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, web-config

I am asking about editing / deleting or adding sections to web.config
I want to be able to add or delete **connectionStrings** section to my web.config file

here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
   </system.webServer>
<connectionStrings />
</configuration>
```

I used the following code to add the section **connectionStrings**

```
 Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
 Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("~/Web.Config")
 doc.Load(path)
 Dim newElem As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("connectionStrings")
 doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newElem)
 doc.PreserveWhitespace = False
 Dim wrtr As XmlTextWriter = New XmlTextWriter(path, Encoding.Unicode)
 doc.WriteTo(wrtr)
 wrtr.Close()
```

I tried to manipulate the code to DELETE the section **connectionStrings**, but i was not able to do it. I used `RemoveChild()` function instead of the `AppendChild()` but i get errors like

```
Error 1 Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Xml.XmlNode'.
```

and

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

can you help me with my code to delete the section **connectionStrings** ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing nodes from an XmlDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611/removing-nodes-from-an-xmldocument)

Comment: Regardless of your problem, this is a bad idea.  When an IIS application's `Web.config` file is edited, the IIS `AppPool` will recycle.  This will cause the thread actually editing the configuration file to terminate and thus terminate the HTTP request, giving a bad UX.  You should not edit the `Web.config` file of a web application from the application itself.  There's also the possible security implications of allowing users of the website to edit its configuration.

Comment: @mason i am sorry sir, i am very novice and i can not use the "duplicate" question you mentioned as a guide. would you please help me with my code to remove the section?

Comment: @mason "connectionstrings"

Comment: @mason can you post it in C#? sorry for bothering sir.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the `connectionstrings` node, go to the parent node (in this case `configuration`) and then use the [`RemoveChild()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.removechild.aspx) function. This is the opposite of the `AppendChild()` function. You'll need to pass in the element you want to delete.

Comment: I get this error: Error 1 Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Xml.XmlNode'.

Comment: now i get this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("~/Web.Config")
doc.Load(path)
Dim connNode As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//connectionStrings")
Dim myparent As XmlNode = connNode.ParentNode
myparent.RemoveChild(connNode)
doc.PreserveWhitespace = False
Dim wrtr As XmlTextWriter = New XmlTextWriter(path,Encoding.Unicode)
doc.WriteTo(wrtr)
wrtr.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You an use 'WebConfigurationManager' class directly to delete the specific key from web.config.
see below code snippet to remove 'connection' string

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("connectionstring");
config.Save();
```