# How to remove specific XML tags from a file and save it back

Tags: c#, xml, tags

I am having the below XML in a file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
      <!--Settings-->
      <add key="url" value="http://vmcarekey.com"/>
      <add key="user" value="admin"/>
      <add key="pass" value="password"/> <!-- Remove this line -->
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I want to remove the xml tag with key="pass" using C# and save the xml in original file.

I want to the output xml looks like as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
      <!--Settings-->
      <add key="url" value="http://vmcarekey.com"/>
      <add key="user" value="admin"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Please guide me to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Linq to xml - read some tutorials and this will be the guide for You. This task is extremely easy.

Comment: Have you researched this at all?  This is the type of thing you will find a LOT of information about.  Your question will receive down votes because you haven't shown any research effort.

Comment: it depend how you read your XML, but you can find an answer there:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611/removing-nodes-from-an-xmldocument

Comment: You mustn't manually edit app.config!

Answer (score 2):

It can easily be done with LinqToXml

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//appSettings/add[@key='pass']").Remove();
xDoc.Save(filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
xdoc.Element("configuration").Element("appSettings").Elements("add")
   .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("key") == "pass").Remove();
xdoc.Save(filename);
```